# Clearing task from a different stack

Tags: android, android-activity

I have activity 1 (SplashActivity) running in foreground.

This splash activity is starting another Activity2 in its onStart() callback.

From elswhere (a singleton running in application context) I want to start Activity3 and to clear the task to make it the new root. This call is done several milliseconds after the other startActivity in onStart() and it fails with this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setTaskFromReuseOrCreateNewTask: task=TaskRecord{df9fb2e #10 A=com.example.myapp.myflavor U=0 StackId=1 sz=0} is in a different stack (1) than the parent of r=ActivityRecord{3b14930 u0 com.example.myapp.myflavor/com.example.myapp.SplashActivity t11} (0)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.reparent(ActivityRecord.java:971)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.addOrReparentStartingActivity(ActivityStarter.java:1992)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.setTaskFromReuseOrCreateNewTask(ActivityStarter.java:1808)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityUnchecked(ActivityStarter.java:1187)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:1002)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:567)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityLocked(ActivityStarter.java:272)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:824)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:4497)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:4464)
at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:121)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2935)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:674)
```

Activities are defined in AndroidManifest.xml in that way:

```
<activity
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:name=".Activity2"/>
<activity
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:name=".Activity3"
    android:noHistory="true"/>
```

Activity2 and Activity3 are started with flag:

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

When the first startActivity is called, the only one task has id 14, and it contains only one activity: the SplashActivity.

When the second startActivity is called, the only one task has id -1 and it contains 0 activities.

So, what would be the solution to have the startActivity robust to the situation where another startActivity is in progress ?

Any idea ?

From what I understand, I would avoid this error by removing the singleTask launchmode, but I need it because my application can be started in different ways...

Other point: The exception is thrown when the application is updated from ADB. When the application is automatically starting at the device start, the exception is not thrown. (My application is the default launcher, so it automatically starts). --> That can probably be explained by a different sequence in the start of the two activities.

Comment: When you are starting it from ADB, can you please turn off your instant run?

Comment: I just tested and it gives the same issue.
However I checked something else, and in fact while I am calling the startActivity, another startActivity is called from the SplashActivity 16 milliseconds before. Perhaps it is linked. I add it in my original question.

Comment: I just refactored my question with my latest inputs.